# How to edit a backported package before uploading it to a PPA?

Tags: ppa, backport, clang

I'm attempting to backport Clang 3.2 to Quantal from Raring. Thinking this would be a relatively painless process, I ran the following command:

```
backportpackage -s raring -d quantal -u ppa:george-edison55/clang3.2-backports clang
```

The package was uploaded to the PPA without any errors and built without any errors as well. Unfortunately, it cannot be installed because the `debian/control` file contains the following dependencies:

```
Depends: ... libgcc-4.7-dev, libobjc-4.7-dev ...
```

Those packages do not exist in Quantal. The contents of those packages is contained in the [gcc-4.7 [image: Install gcc-4.7]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcc-4.7) and [gobjc-4.7 [image: Install gobjc-4.7]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gobjc-4.7) packages instead. My problem is that I have no idea how to make the change before uploading the package to my PPA.

I tried instructing `backportpackage` not to upload to my PPA and dump the files in `/tmp/clang3.2` where I edited them. However, attempting to upload the package simply results in the original `.tar.gz` being downloaded again and overwriting my changes.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Even though there's `-w` option that tells backportpackage to preserve the working directory, there's still no way to tell it keep the unpacked (and modified) sources as well. So here's what worked for me:

1. Copy the program locally to modify it:

   `cp /usr/bin/backportpackage ~`
2. Open the local file and find *do_backport* function. Its last line should look like

   shutil.rmtree(srcdir)
3. Delete that line, save the file, and run the script as you normally do it, make sure to provide `-w` option to specify the working directory.
4. Go to the working directory. There should be sub-directory with the name like *<package>-<dist>*, e.g. *gcc-xenial*.
5. `cd` to that directory, do whatever changes you want to do.
6. Make a debian package. Sign and upload the result:

   `debuild --no-lintian -S -nc -uc -us -sd`

   `debsign ../<package-version>_source.changes`

   `dput -u ppa:<user>/<repo> <package-version>_source.changes`